# Computing the mean of a 2D array CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I need to compute the mean of a 2D array using CUDA, but I don't know how to proceed. I started by doing column reduction after that I will make the sum of the resulting array, and in the last step I will compute the mean.

To do this I need to do the whole work on the device at once? or I just do step by step and each step need a back and forth to and from the CPU and The GPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's simple arithmetic mean of all the elements in 2D array you can use thrust:

```
int* data;
int num;
get_data_from_library( &data, &num );

thrust::device_vector< int > iVec(data, data+num);

// transfer to device and compute sum
int sum = thrust::reduce(iVec.begin(), iVec.end(), 0, thrust::plus<int>());
double mean = sum/(double)num;
```

If you want to write your own kernel - keep in mind that 2D array is essentially an 1D array divided into row-size chunks and go through SDK 'parallel reduction' example : [Whitepaper](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf)

Comment: Thank you @pSoLT for your answer, Really im new to CUDA, what I undertand from your answer is that there si already kernel to do that? is yes, it is optimized or I can do a better kernel? what is teh better ? to use this one or create my own kernel? thank you in advanced

Comment: You are welcome @alae. There is a library called [`Thrust`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/)  , which is basically an CUDA template library based on STL. It allows you to use CUDA in some typical problems without to much effort (as you probably notice).  `Thrust` algorithms are pretty optimal, so I doubt you can achieve better results in array reduction using your own kernel. It would be a very good exercise though.

Comment: Thank you very much @pSoLT for your answer it is pretty clear and precise ^^